# How can parse this data when one field change of name?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I am trying to make several POJOs using `Json.fromJson`, to parse a `String json` to a POJO.

To make this I have the following class:

```
public class Queue {

    @SerializedName("reference")
    @Expose
    private String reference;

    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private QueuesTypes type;

    @SerializedName("desc")
    @Expose
    private String desc;

    @SerializedName("alias")
    @Expose
    private String alias;

    private QueueObjects queueObjects;

}
```

As you can see all objects have their notations less the last because in this case is not the same.

Sometimes that label should be `calls`, or `whatsapps` or `tweets`, according to the information.

And this Queue Object that can has different attributes to the last object because is merged in the response like this:

```
{"success":true,"data":[
    {"reference":"","type":"","desc":"","alias":"","calls":[{fromPhone:'', toPhone:''}]}, 
    {"reference":"","type":"","desc":"","alias":"","whatsapps": [message:'']},
    {"reference":"","type":"","desc":"","alias":"","calls":[fromPhone:'', toPhone:'']},
    {"reference":"","type":"","desc":"","alias":"","calls":[fromPhone:'', toPhone:'']},
    {"reference":"","type":"","desc":"","alias":"","whatsapps": [message:''],}
    {"reference":"","type":"","desc":"","alias":"","fax": [fromFax:'', toFax:'', message:'']}]
```

So this is a:

```
public class SocketQueueResponse {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private boolean success;

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Queue> listQueue;
}
```

The problem is how can put several attributes with its several kind ob objects according to the response in QueueClass.

Now I have

public interface QueueObjects {
}

And another class according to the response, but the problem is how can set the notation to QueueObjects.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should create many different subclasses (one for `calls`, one for `whatsapps`, etc) and then use a type adapter to determine which one to deserialize. This article has a reasonable-looking overview of this strategy: https://medium.com/@int02h/custom-deserialization-with-gson-1bab538c0bfa

Comment: I have those classes, the problem is how can tell to retrofit or Gson, that the last field is a particular object and use a particular parser only for that attribute.

Comment: remove private QueueObjects queueObjects; add QueueCallObjects calls,QueueWhatsappsObjects whatsapps,QueueFAXObjects fax

Comment: I thought that option but I want to know if there are other options

Comment: As the article says, your `deserialize()` method can say e.g. `if (jsonObject.has("calls")) return context.deserialize(jsonObject, CallsSubtype.class)` and `else if (jsonObject.has("whatsapps")) return context.deserialize(jsonObject, WhatsappSubclass.class)`, etc

Comment: Your response JSON string is invalid, e.g. some field names are not wrapped with double-quote, some empty strings should be `""` not `''` and some JSON objects in a JSON array should be embraced with `{}`.

Comment: I wrote '' and {} because I dont want specify the current values. @LHCHIN

Comment: @BenP. how can I specify in the notation the class to parser that field?